# how to change data in the column as "N" automatically instead of deleting, after selecting the checkbox &click on delete button

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

When I am inserting a record into the table, in the "state" column I am inserting "A".
Now I want to automatically change that "A" to "N" after I have checked the checkbox and clicked on the delete button.

Can you please help me?

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            int cnt= int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string sql = "delete from PA_webwork where sno = @sno ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", cnt);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

---

```
   database     :: web
   table name   :: PA_webwork

   column names ::

            sno         :: int
            article no  :: varchar(50)
            state       :: varchar(50)
            date        :: smalldatetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can write update statement

```
            int cnt= int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string sql = "update  PA_webwork set state 'N'  where sno = @sno ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", cnt);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot on those days .. thanks @Knn 
This is the my first post in Stackoverflow in 2013. At that time I forgot to put comment for this, Now i recalled you and came back to this :) Thanks Keep rocking..!